# Why am I able to use datetime in pandas without importing datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I don't quite understand when I must import datetime and when it's not necessary. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df['date_string_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_string_col'])
df['datetime_year_col'] = df['date_string_col'].dt.year
```

Why does this work without importing `datetime`? Moreover, shouldn't I have to alias the import as `dt` for that second statement to work?

Comment: You don't import `datetime`, you import `pandas`

Comment: @mozway Ok, so does that mean pandas automatically imports datetime as dt? I don't think I have full datetime functionality without importing datetime.

Comment: .dt is an attribute of the series. If you check, that series will have a datalike dtype. This is called [accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing a bunch of concepts. [`pd.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) is a pandas accessor, as highlighted in the docs.

> Accessor object for datetimelike properties of the Series values.

This has been coded by the pandas core dev team, and is [open source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.1/pandas/core/indexes/accessors.py#L545-L580). They coded things following some conventions similar to the default `datetime` package (e.g. `strftime`), but there's no dependency. Things were developed according to how they wanted.

In addition, doing `import datetime as dt` has literally no effect in what is accessible or not via `pd.Series.dt`, they are separate things. When you work with a `pd.Series` with `datetime64` dtype, the objects being held in the array are *not* py`datetime` objects, but instead [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) values. From the docs,

> Pandas replacement for python datetime.datetime object.
> Timestamp is the pandas equivalent of python’s Datetime and is interchangeable with it in most cases. It’s the type used for the entries that make up a DatetimeIndex, and other timeseries oriented data structures in pandas.

You can always move back and forth from pandas to py using `to_pydatetime()` e.g.:

```
>>> pd_vals = pd.date_range('2023-05-05', '2023-05-07')
DatetimeIndex(['2023-05-05', '2023-05-06', '2023-05-07'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', 
              freq='D')

>>> pd_vals.to_pydatetime()
array([datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 5, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 6, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 7, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

But by doing so, you'd lose most of pandas vectorization capabilities, which is what makes the library so powerful.

The idea is that pandas will abstract the datetime backend lib used, and provide you only the functionalities you need. The user doesn't need to bother whether the backend is pydatetime.

Comment: Great response. This completely clarifies things for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, because it's a built-in function in pandas. `to_datetime` converts date and time in string format to a DateTime object. `dt.year` is also a built-in function that allows you to preview the year.